# Where should the line be drawn regarding political statements in a scientific report?

Tags: research-process, physics, politics

I am writing a report on Fusion energy as an assignment. It contributes to a sperate qualification in Physics which is simply a Pass/Fail. Further studies will often not accept students who do not pass this section.

In this report, I have briefly looked into the current state of electricity generation, including the emissions from coal power plants, and the mining of coal. I found some excellent sources, but also one that had been deleted from the state.gov website. It was available [here](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/219038.pdf). It is still available on archive.org [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161223091651/http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/219038.pdf).

Archive.org shows it was removed sometime between 12:45 and 19:54 on the 20th of January 2017. This does not seem to be a coincidence as many news sites reported on [Trump ordering the EPA to remove climate change data](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-epa-climatechange-idUSKBN15906G).

Personal politics aside, I feel attempting to remove/removing any data from the internet is disgraceful, and I want to express that in my report. Currently, at the end of my bibliography I have this text:

> Note on Citation 30: UNITED STATES CLIMATE ACTION REPORT 2014. The Available URL provided is from archive.org’s WaybackMachine, a project which aims to archive public facing sites for the future, protecting them from removal. On the 20th of January 2017, this report was removed from the state.gov website. This appears to have been under the instruction of President Trump, as news sites reported data on the EPA website was removed. The provided archive.org link is the most recent version, from 23 December 2016.

Is this appropriate in the bibliography, or should I simply leave it at the first 2 sentences?

Comment: The only question is really the 3rd sentence. I'll say this: even if the consensus is to take it out, most people will be able to infer what happened. IMO it barely counts as a political statement. Good on you for catching it.

Comment: Another example, removed on the 21st: http://web.archive.org/web/20170113142520/https://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2016/11/264407.htm, another removed between the 21st and 27th: http://web.archive.org/web/20170121024458/http://www.state.gov/e/oes/climate/mem/

Comment: The entire State Dept website is [archived on an administration change](https://www.state.gov/misc/112234.htm). The old State Dept website, including [the document you are referring to](https://2009-2017.state.gov/documents/organization/219038.pdf), is still available - you just need to use the "2009-2017.state.gov" URL instead of "state.gov".

Comment: @ff524 Why is some data still left on the new site? It is still available, but the information on the current site does seem to have been cherry picked?

Comment: Because every new administration decides what should be on their new State Dept. site. They can keep some of the old stuff or not. The old stuff is [archived](https://www.state.gov/misc/112234.htm) and is still available, just not at the same URL.

Comment: `It was available here. It is still available on archive.org here.` And `...attempting to remove/removing any data from the internet...`. Since you seem to have found it **on the Internet**, it's not clear what the actual problem is. Tried recently to retrieve early WinXP fixes and even a lot of docs from Microsoft? Stuff is 'removed from the Internet' all the time. Hard to find persistent sites that don't remove stuff. Not necessarily 'data' as such, though uncountable examples of it are possible.

Comment: @user2338816 the problem is the apparent removal of files talking about climate change from the state.gov web site...

Comment: Understood, yet you indeed found it **on the Internet**. It's not really a set of 'data' but rather an out-of-date description of governmental activity around climate change. What you should look at (complain about) is the current [2016 Climate Action Report](https://www.state.gov/e/oes/climate/climateactionreport/index.htm?goMobile=0) which links to [the doc at whitehouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/docs/mid_century_strategy_report-final.pdf). (And yes, I disappointedly know about those links, but the 2016 report is available.)

Comment: Sometimes what's left unsaid says more than what is said.

Comment: Since the data in question was not removed from `*.gov`, much less "the internet", the entire premise is invalid.  Rather than giving the Wayback URI, give the `2009-2017.state.gov` URI, which will presumably be maintained indefinitely, and drop the speculation.

Comment: @MontyHarder right sure I get that now. Many other comments have pointed out it is still available. The question was based on me not being able to find it on state.gov, and while the reason for the question no longer applies, the question title is still file, and the answers apply no matter what mistake I made accessing the data. It also doesn't remove from the fact that this document wasn't transferred over. I'm sure they had their reasons for that.

Comment: “I feel attempting to remove/removing any data from the internet is disgraceful” — why not express *this* in the report, rather than making it about people and idle speculation? The removal of the report from the WH website has actually inconvenienced your research, and it would be absolutely acceptable to point this out in passing in a paper.

Comment: @MontyHarder: is there any commitment from the US State Dept on how long `2009-2017.state.gov` will be maintained (or Wayback's archive, for that matter)? (For that matter, is the Bush 2001-2009 state.gov available?)

Comment: "I feel attempting to remove/removing any data from the internet is disgraceful".  So It was disgraceful for me to delete the video of my cat playing the piano from my website?

Comment: @James yeah. Why on earth would you do that? On a serious note, I don't like data being removed. It's so easy nowadays to hit delete, when it was a conscious action to burn a book in the Nast...

Comment: @smci you can go to `http://2001-2009 state.gov` and see for yourself that it is up right now.  I don't speak for the US government, so I can't say how long it will be maintained, but the fact that it's still there two administrations later suggests there's no reason it won't be maintained indefinitely for historical purposes. This isn't just a problem for government sites, by the way.  Lots of commercial sites reorganize things from time to time, rendering URIs unusable. I think it's less common in an academic context where having stable citations is standard practice.

Comment: @MontyHarder and there's even an archive of Clinton's second term: https://1997-2001 state.gov . But I don't see a clear guarantee that it will continue to be there permanently, or that selected bits won't disappear or be moved, arbitrarily. Yes I know that archival and stale URLs is a generic issue, but this is about preserving public records. Unlike the State Dept, some conservatives want to abolish the EPA, Dept of Education etc.

Comment: @smci Assume, arguendo, the Dept. of Education is abolished. The law abolishing the agency would need to reallocate authority/responsibility currently held by the Secretary of Education to some other Cabiniet-level agency.  Perhaps the spinoff of Education from HEW (leaving behind HHS) would be reversed.  In any event, _some_ agency of the US govt. would inherit `ed.gov` and maintain those public records.  Ironically, that might mean leaving those URIs intact, and putting the new content at the new domain. The bigger problem is that documents are posted with temporary URIs in the first place.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> This appears to have been under the instruction of President Trump, as news sites reported data on the EPA website was removed.

Speculation usually doesn't belong in a scientific paper. This is especially true when it does not further the scientific purpose of the paper.

The rest of the statement - about the document no longer being available at its original link, and a note regarding its availability on archive.org, is fine because it is not speculation and serves an academic purpose. However, you actually don't need to resort to archive.org, because [the document is still available](https://2009-2017.state.gov/documents/organization/219038.pdf) on the archived state.gov site.

Like whitehouse.gov, the entire State Department website is routinely [archived](https://www.state.gov/misc/112234.htm) at the end of each administration, and the new administration can put whatever they want on their new site. (For example, at the beginning of the Obama administration, they replaced the [Bush-era State Department site on climate change](http://web.archive.org/web/20090113205754/http://www.state.gov/g/oes/climate/index.htm) with [their own](http://web.archive.org/web/20090124153057/http://state.gov/g/oes/climate/index.htm).) The state.gov material from the Obama administration is still available; you just have to replace "www.state.gov" in the URL with "2009-2017.state.gov".

(P.S. an archive of the EPA website immediately before the transition, created [in response to numerous FOIA requests](https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/16/the-epa-posted-a-backup-of-its-website-dated-just-before-inauguration-day/), is also available: https://19january2017snapshot.epa.gov/)

Comment: +1. It seems that the government is actually being more considerate about keeping their data available than most universities here.

Comment: @darij.grinberg Although they are just as inconsiderate about keeping URLs available: [cool URLs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: Then again, it would have been a bit presumptuous for Barack Obama to have claimed `2009-2017.state.gov` when he entered office ;)

Comment: @MSalters Yes, this sounds more like something Trump would do. But there are more neutral options, such as state.gov/44th-administration/.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: better they maintain an authoritative archive than people start to use "alternative" archives I guess

Comment: “Speculation usually doesn't belong in a scientific paper.” — Err yes it does; speculation has always been a firmly established part of scientific discourse. In modern biology papers, it’s usually, but not exclusively, found in the “discussion” section. ;-) (No disagreement about this specific instance though.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Presumably that would be the kind that _does_ "further the scientific purpose of the paper."

Answer (score 27):

> Personal politics aside, I feel attempting to remove/removing any data from the internet is disgraceful, and I want to express that in my report

Well, that isn't putting personal politics aside, is it? That is literally going out of your way to put personal politics into your report. It doesn't belong there. Don't do it!

Instead, use your blog or local pub to vent your frustration on the matter. Meanwhile, cite the source material as succinctly and as factually as you can, without veering into unnecessary speculation.

As a general rule, if you have to ask whether something's appropriate then the answer is usually "no".

Comment: My point was whichever side had done it, its bad. That feels a-political.

Comment: @Tim: It's your opinion on an action by a political body. "Good" vs "bad" is your opinion, not an absolute that everybody automatically agrees with you on. Your opinion has no place in a citation.

Comment: @Tim That just make it an *honest/reasoned* political opinion. But definitely not a-political.

Answer (score 6):

It is Fact versus Speculation.

Fact: The report was available but it was taken down.
Speculation: The report was available and [Walter Plinge] had it taken down.

If you write scientific article about technology, stay apolitical and stick to the facts.

If you want to comment on the fact you are referring to `archive.org` instead of `state.gov` servers consider this way:

> Note on Citation 30: UNITED STATES CLIMATE ACTION REPORT 2014. The Available URL provided is from archive.org’s WaybackMachine, a project which aims to archive public facing sites for the future, protecting them from removal. On the 20th of January 2017, this report was removed from the state.gov website. <strike>This appears to have been under the instruction of President Trump, as news sites reported data on the EPA website was removed.</strike> The provided archive.org link from 23 December 2016 is the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

As ff524 mentioned, speculation should not belong in scientific paper.

However, I do want to add that in this or similar kind of cases, mentioning that document availability (or its removal) is depending on political powers might be somewhat relevant. Papers, data or documents could be removed because huge error was found, or data was deemed outdated.

If the reader has no knowledge why the document has been removed, I believe most likely conclusion would be that the removed document is faulty and should not be used as source. Especially for those outside USA who might not know the practise of removing stuff when government changes.

I would not try to take political stance here though, and keep the statement of removal as neutral as possible. In this case it seems that you can link to the archived government site, so statement might not be necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

'appears' is [subjective/argumentative](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-the-opposite-of-argumentative). The 1st 2nd and 4th sentences are objective/factual.

I think the 3rd sentence is okay if you can concisely defend your claim.

Of course, 'concisely' may be subjective too :P